# measurement protocol - User timing category

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics, measurement-protocol

My user timing syntax does not log any activity in real time tab for google analytics.
Am I missing any parameter , here is the request

http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-xxx-2&cid=555123&t=timing&utc=jsonloader&utv=load&utt=5000&utl=jquerylabel

Answer (score -1):

It works, had to include today's date to view the data.

Comment: Where do you include the date?